# How to extract features from variable duration time-series data?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, random-forest

I have 4 different data sets with samples of time-series measurements of different actions. The duration (# data points) of each measurement in the different sets is:

```
Set # 1 = 40000 data points  
Set # 2 = 8000 data points
Set # 3 = 5000 data points 
Set # 4 = 40000 data points
```

My plan was to have a window size of 100 data points over which to calculate features such (mean, kurtosis, variance..etc); however, since the time-series measurements are of different lengths, would it be appropriate to adjust the window size for each set so that I will have the same number of features across all samples? Or is there a better approach?

The purpose of these features is for multi-class classification using an svm or random forests model.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit. If i understand you correctly, you're building features $x_1$ such that it is the average of the first 100 points, and $x_2$ the average of the next 100 pts in a time series, and so on. So the features themselves are time series, is that what you're thinking?

Comment: @horaceT. Yes, exactly that is the approach I am considering.

Comment: Now, tell us something about the nature of these observations. Are they recorded at the same frequency, ie. Set 1 is recorded every minute, while Set 2 every 15 min, etc. Depending on the time nature of the information, you may choose different strategy.

Comment: Oh sorry, yes each data set is the sensor output of a specific action event measured at a sample rate of 800Hz. There are 10 actions of the same class in each data set, they are independent of each other, and I have segmented them into 10 samples of equal duration. The problem is the duration of an action is variable between the 4 classes.

Comment: Recurrent neural networks are designed to take variable-length sequences as inputs (eg, they can be easily trained on sequences of different length and even different measurement frequency) and output some probability distribution over class labels. In your case, this might mean using as input the time-series *as is* without any need to extract features (aggregated or otherwise) or resample.  Alternatively, HMMs might apply.